# what is this symbol on the boot screen ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: boot, 20.04, linux-headers

[image: Picture]

Every time i turn on the pc this symbol appears, before the lenovo logo and the ubuntu symbol appeared.

Comment: It's Ubuntu-Budgie. Haven't you installed as an additional desktop?

Comment: @ChanganAuto If you know what it is, then please post an answer instead of a comment. Thanks!

Comment: @cocomac I know what it is but I would like to first have confirmation the OP understands why it is there.

Comment: @cocomac I installed the plank, but removed it and after that this image appeared.